# Golang C bindings type design

Tags: c, go, binding, shared-libraries, wrapper

```
type Foobar C.struct_foobar
```

vs.

```
type Foobar struct {
    foobar C.struct_foobar
}
```

Which one has which (dis)advantages for writing Golang bindings for a C lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example clearly shows a data structure not accessible from other packages.

With the first one this would be impossible.